Swagger request body section not showing
I am using Express. I have installed Swagger and Swagger UI. It works but not showing request body section.
/**
 * @swagger
 * /your/endpoint:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Endpoint summary
 *     description: Endpoint description
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               query:
 *                 type: string
 *               oldestFirst:
 *                 type: boolean
 *               pagination:
 *                 type: object
 *                 properties:
 *                   itemsPerPage:
 *                     type: integer
 *                   pageIndex:
 *                     type: integer
 *     responses:
 *       '200':
 *         description: Successful operation
 */

I want to show requestBody section.

I assume this is a difference between OpenAPI (v3) and Swagger (v2): try a parameter in: body and see if that renders https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/.
